# Static linking with Qt third-party libraries

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm currently trying to build a Qt 5.8 under Linux statically with builtin third party libraries.
Here is my config:

```
./configure -static -prefix ~/Qt/5.8/static -opensource -confirm-license -openssl-linked -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-xcb -qt-xkbcommon -qt-freetype -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples
```

Then i building my app with CONFIGURE += static option
Resulted binary still have some dependencies, but it shouldn't.
ldd output (shorted for simplicity):

```
libtiff.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5 
libwebp.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.5 
libwebpdemux.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpdemux.so.1 
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 
libEGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-361/libEGL.so.1 (0x00007f9334bce000)
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 
libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 
libjbig.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjbig.so.0 
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f93315ba000)
```

As you see, binary stil looking for jpeg tiff and png somewhere in the system

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? The answer below does not work for me. It actually makes the linker fail, saying, e.g., /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgbm (and i have libgbm-dev installed)

Answer (score 0):

A static Qt build will only link Qt libraries statically, nothing else. You will still have various dynamic link library dependencies.

You don't need `CONFIGURE += static` in your project, what you need is to pass a linker flag instead via `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static`.